# What is the difference between not found and not followed in Google Webmaster Tools?

Tags: google-search-console, crawl-errors

In Google Webmaster Tools under Crawl Errors I found 18 Not Found and 16 Not Followed errors.

What does this mean, and what is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Found means the Googlebot tried to go to the page but it was either missing, renamed, had a typo in it, or was incorrect in your sitemap.

Not Followed means the Googlebot had trouble following a link because of things like it contained session ID's, complicated JavaScript, Flash, frames, iFrames, DHTML, or invalid redirects...

This is not to say that Google won't crawl things like JavaScript or iFrames, in fact it will, but you might receive an error if they are very complex.

Comment: Will it be a serious issue for my site?

Comment: Errors are common. How serious they are depends on how crucial it is to have those links indexed. If you have links to them in your site where people can find them easily however, that's less of an issue.

Comment: Also see, the following three sections that might help you to reduce errors: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=35769#1